# И снова запятая перед как

Tags: пунктуация

Как участник Великой Отечественной войны отец награжден многими юбилейными медалями, почетными грамотами. Нужно ли выделить запятыми оборот с как, здесь вроде подходит и "в качестве" и по "причине". Как правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В приведенном вами примере оборот с как имеет причинное значение, запятая необходима. Вряд ли можно наградить человека в качестве участника войны. Его наградили потому, что он - участник войны.

Answer (score 0):

> ...запятая необходима.

**НЕ СОГЛАСЕН.**

**P.S.**

Конечно, запятая **может** быть поставлена. Но **значительно чаще** она в таких предложениях НЕ СТАВИТСЯ.